# Find A, B, C that generate power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, find subsets $A, B, C$ that together generate the power set of $X$, i.e. $\sigma( \{A,B,C\} ) = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

I am not sure where to begin. Could I maybe take $A  = 1, B = 2, C = 3$, use them to obtain $4$ and $5$, and then note that any set in the power set is just a union of these?

Answer (score 0):

No, with $A=1,B=2,C=3$, you cannot generate $\{4\}$ and $\{5\}$ separately.

Try $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{2,3,4\}$, $C=\{3,4,5\}$. Then, for example $$\{1\}=(A\triangle B)\backslash C.$$
Can you work out the rest?